# Non-root methods to mount USB storage devices

Tags: usb, mount

From my understanding, one can use `StickMount` to mount USB Sticks / Thumbdrive. However, `StickMount` require one to root phone.

So, are there ways that I can mount a USB Sticks / Thumbdrive to a Android phone / tablet without rooting the phone?

Comment: This maybe of interest http://blog.gsmarena.com/sony-launches-a-dual-usb-flash-drive-geared-towards-android-smartphones-and-tablets/

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your device. Sone Android devices have USB ports that can work in host mode or support [USB OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_OTG). These devices can at least have read access to the USB drives, some can even use them as full mounts. One app that allows read access on a lot of devices is [Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer). You can use it to browse media and copy files to internal storage.

Comment: I notice that the `Nexus Media Importer` require a Android phone with Android version 3.2 or above. Are there any for Android version below 3.2?

Comment: "USB host mode is supported in Android 3.1 and higher." ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html))

Comment: Thanks for the information. May I assume that there are no solution for Android version below 3.1? (e.g. those using 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and below)

Comment: There are, but these are (as far as I know) device-dependent, there's no general solution.